# how to access hyperlink inside textBlock?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, canvas, hyperlink, ienumerable

I have a canvas on which i have a textBlock, and i have a hyperlink inside textBlock. i can access the canvas on my grid and Textblock on the canvas with following code, but dnt know how to access hyperlink inside textBlock, ANy idea guys ?

```
    canvas+textBlock+hyperlink code:


          <Canvas Grid.Column="2" ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" Background="Beige" Margin="12,25" Grid.RowSpan="2"   >
          <TextBlock FontSize="15" Name="tbmarquee" Canvas.Left="10" Width="169"> 
           <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com"  RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"  Cursor="Hand" >
                                <!--Google page link--> 
          </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        </Canvas>
```

and i Access the canvas and TextBlock dynamically with following code:

```
     IEnumerable<Canvas> cnvss = this.gride.Children.OfType<Canvas>();
                foreach (Canvas cnvs in cnvss)
                {
     IEnumerable<TextBlock> txs = cnvs.Children.OfType<TextBlock>();
                         foreach(TextBlock tbs in txs )
                        {

                        }
                }
```

How to access the hyperlink ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get `Hyperlink` from `TextBlock`'s `Inlines` property, for example :

```
var h = tbs.Inlines.OfType<Hyperlink>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: and if i want to add text to h , how to do it ? coz i want to access hyperlink to change its text dynamically... but h.text wont work, any way to to assign text to it ???

Comment: adding requirement on the go is bad, next time you should've stated that from the beginning or make it a separate question.

Comment: Anyway, that depends on whether you want to *change existing text* or *add new text* to the hyperlink..